# Buying Prebuilt 32 bit Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a lot of 32 bit hardware drivers for printers, scanners, etc.. and I was looking to buy a new computer with 32 bit Windows 7 and 3 GB RAM. All of my current computers are kinda old with only 1 GB RAM so I'll be happy with 3 GB RAM.

When I go to the websites for Dell and HP, I only see options for 64 bit windows 7. Do any of the major OEMs offer 32 bit windows 7? I know that I can build my own machine and buy a 32 bit Windows 7 license, but I was hoping to find a pre-built system. Thanks!

Comment: Something else you might want to consider. I believe that Windows 7 requires that all device drivers be digitally signed. In other words, unless the manufacturer has provided a driver which will work in Windows 7 or the driver is included in Windows 7, your old hardware still may not work. You might want to look into that further before you decide what you're going to do.

Comment: @irration john, the driver signing requirement is only for Windows 7 64-bit. 32-bit can run unsigned drivers.

@Daniel, I hope you know that Windows 7 installs a lot of drivers for printers/scanners automatically. Try checking the Windows 7 Compatibility Center to see if your hardware is listed there.

Comment: It is listed on the compatibility chart as being okay, but doesn't work in 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the media 32 bits Windows 7 installation media you can use it with a 64 bits license. Just buy a PC as you would like from Dell/HP/YourChoice and try to get a 32 bits media with them or Microsoft - Microsoft probably will have a shipping fee a new installation media.

Comment: Are there limitations on the type of CPU Processor that I can use? I see some chips which list 64 in their name. Would they run on a 32 bit Windows?

Comment: @Daniel - The Intel & AMD processors which support 64-bits all still support the 32-bit mode. You can run either 64 or 32 bit windows on an x86_64 enable processor. (Which frankly is just about any "new" processor you're likely to buy now.)